# Как заменить точки на запятые в lua?

Tags: lua

```
String = "Hello. my name is XXX!"       
Changed = String:gsub(".", ",")       
print(Changed)
```

Результат.

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Как сделать так чтобы оно заменяло точки на запятые?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хоть задача и решена, но могу предложить несколько другой вариант:

```lua
Changed = String:gsub("%.", ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

Решено.

```
:gsub("[.]", ",")
```